# Is there any utility in unix like minus operator in sql

Tags: sql, shell, unix

I am fetching  records from two different databases and keeping them in two separate files suppose `File1.txt` and `File2.txt` .

I want to compare these two files as we do in case of sql minus operator.

Suppose if File1.txt contains data like

```
COL1|COL2|COL3
A1|A2|A3
B1|B2|B3
```

and File2.txt contains data like

```
COL1|COL2|COL3
A1|A2|A3
C1|C2|C3
```

I want to do something like File1.txt minus File2.txt so that I will get `B1|B2|B3` as output and if File2.txt minus File1.txt I will get `C1|C2|C3`.

How can I achieve this in shell scripting. Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `grep` like this:

```
grep -F -x -v -f file2 file1
```

Note that:

```
-F FILE takes patterns from FILE

-x match whole line

-v show non-matching
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `comm` is for

```
comm -23 file1 file2 # b...
comm -13 file1 file2 # c...
```

Check your `comm` man page

The input needs to be sorted. The final answer might be a little more complicated.

Comment: Worth noting, given that this appears to be database output and we don't have the actual data to consider, that `comm` is usually limited by LINE_MAX.  On my system, that's 2048 bytes.  +1 anyway; it's always good to see the "older" tools still in use.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare based on a common *field* rather than on complete lines, then you may be able to script a solution in awk.  For example,

```
awk -F '|' 'NR==FNR{keys[$1]++;next;} $1 in keys{next;} 1' File2.txt File1.txt
```

This reads the first "column" of File2.txt into an array, `keys[]`, and then steps through File1.txt, skipping any line whose key matches one found in File2.txt, and printing the rest.  It works on the sample data in your question, even if you change the content of columns 2 or 3 in either file.

Of course, if you're dealing with a billion records in File2.txt, they may not fit in the memory that's available to awk.